# Automatic mixed mode H2 with shared store JDBC Url

Tags: h2

Is it recommended to use a network based shared storage file system to create and use the DB files generated by H2 in persistent automatic mixed mode?

I have a server cluster for high availability and all nodes view the same shared directory which is located in a network attached store: `jdbc:h2:file:\\networkstore\h2dir`.
This lets the cluster work fine even if a node crashes because another node will become the primary node and load the DB in embedded mode. However, if the network connection fails at some point then the embedded server loses DB connectivity. Additionally, it has been observed that connectivity issues can end up corrupting the database, maybe due to partial writes in the DB file? I have been able to corrupt the H2 file just by playing around with my ethernet cable.

Is automatic mixed mode supposed to be used in a cluster of *Primary Applications* instead of a multiservice application with a single primary node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It's a very bad idea to store database files on network file systems, no matter which DBMS you choose, databases need reliable file systems.
2. Automatic mixed mode in H2 isn't really safe and it doesn't support access to the same database from different hosts.
3. If your application can crash, don't use embedded H2 in it, use remote connections to database server.

You need to start a standalone H2 Server process on some reliable host and use client connections to it from your nodes. You can also to use clustering capabilites of H2 to start more than one database server, but this feature is basically unmaintained and has various limitations. There are also third-party solutions such as HA-JDBC. It is also possible that H2 isn't really suitable for your needs.

Comment: I  thought so. We want to avoid dedicated Database Service due to installation overhead on our customers (we provide an on-prem product which means less work for them is less work for us). H2 seemed like a good solution for this but I guess these subtleties undermine the whole idea.